# Scrollview is bouncing back

Tags: iphone

I have a app where in once I tap on a textfield it slides on top of keyboard.

My scrollview is bouncing back when I scroll down my content. iPhone documentation says "by default, it “bounces” back when scrolling exceeds the bounds of the content."

Any clue how to get rid of this? Should I increase the content size of scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop a `UIScrollView` from bouncing:

```
UIScrollView *myScrollView; ...
[myScrollView setBounces:NO];
```

If your question was about the scrolling behavior being different when the keyboard is on screen, double check that you have set the autoresize behavior of the Views appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried it but it did not work :(. This issue has given me a big headache. This happens only when keyboard comes up and I select a textfield and then scroll it down the keyboard. Otherwise it works fine. Please suggest something. At first place why [myScrollView setBounces:NO] is not stopping my scroll view to stop bouncing back.

Comment: Also, one more point here. When keyboard is up, I am able to scroll the view properly but If i keep the textfield (tapping on which this keyboard pop up) below the keyboard and click on my done button in my view it bounces my scroll out of frame. This does not happen if I do not scroll down the textfield below the keyboard.